# Change timezone in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, time-zone

I'm working with a server with Ubuntu 12.04. I need to change the timezone from `Europe/London` to `America/Sao_Paulo`.

On this server I have Apache2, MySQL, phpMyAdmin, R and others installed.

Do I have to restart each service from the command line manually or is there something more practical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way, per [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime), to do this from the command line, is:

```
echo "America/Sao_Paulo" | sudo tee /etc/timezone
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

You shouldn't have to restart any service after that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, and broadly speaking most general way to find an answer to this kind of questions, is to issue the command:

```
  man -k keyword
```

The *-k* flag specifies that what follows is a keyword, not the exact name of a command. In your case it produces the following output:

```
 # man -k timezone
 Time::Zone (3pm)     - - miscellaneous timezone manipulations routines
 timezone (3)         - initialize time conversion information
 tzfile (5)           - timezone information
 tzselect (1)         - view timezones
 tzselect (8)         - select a timezone
 zdump (8)            - timezone dumper
 zic (8)              - timezone compiler
```

This show that *tzselect* is a promising command. *man 1 tzselect* will display the manual entry for *tzselect* in the first section, and, among the input, you find:

> tzselect - view timezones
>
> ........................
>
> Note that tzselect will not actually change the timezone for you. Use 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' to achieve this.

And now you have the answer to your question.